# WE8DEC (or MCS) encoding in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, encoding

Okay, I have this big .NET project which uses multiple databases with a lot of already-written requests. The databases all uses [WE8DEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_Character_Set) as the character system, until now, all the data was latin and there was no problem.

But I now have the task to use a new database, again in WE8DEC, but this database stores russian data, written in cyrillic. Using a tool like DBeaver, it shows data like `ÇÎËÎÒÀ�ÅÂ` instead of the actual cyrillic text.

I know I can retrieve the byte data directly from the database using the [dump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635) function to retrieve the bytes and then convert them.

```
WORD        | DUMP(WORD)
ÇÎËÎÒÀ�ÅÂ   | Typ=1 Len=9: 199,206,203,206,210,192,208,197,194
```

But I don't feel like duplicating/altering all my request and the way I retrieve the results in c#, I have a place just before sending the data as JSON where I could just reincode all the string before sending them.

So I was looking for a way to retrieve the bytes just like in Oracle and found a way using this line of code :

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(word);
```

But my main problem is this, I don't find any exact equivalent of the WE8DEC encoding from Oracle in .NET, `Windows-1252` is the closest I found (but still incorrect).

So the question, is there an exact equivalent of WE8DEC, also called MCS, in c#?

Comment: Have you tried 
iso-8859-5 
 
Cyrillic (ISO)

Comment: @Kevin Yes, but it gives totally differents bytes `{67, 73, 69, 73, 79, 65, 63, 65, 65}`. You see, the complicated part must come from the fact that I first retrieve the string just as in the database, so decoding looks something like this : `byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5").GetBytes("ÇÎËÎÒÀ�ÅÂ")`.

Comment: `WE8DEC` does not support Cyrillic characters, so you can't use it. Perhaps the DB stores some characters which "you try to interpret as Cyrillic characters". If your client application shows Cyrillic characters then this application is wrongly configured and just **fortunate coincidence**! I would recommend to migrate your DB to Unicode, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) or store relevant data as `BLOB`, resp. `RAW` or as `BASE64` then you can do you own conversion.